# recover values from ipyparallel map if a single evaluation failed

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I run a quite time consuming (>3 days) simulation using ipyparallel's map function like that in Jupyter Notebook

```
from ipyparallel import Client
rc = Client()
lview = rc.load_balanced_view()
ar = lview.map(runsimulation, parameter)
```

and I really need those results. But unfortunately a single instance died because of memory starvation. Now i can not access the result using ar[i] anymore. Is there a chance to recover all the other results that where most certainly computed (I can see the characteristic memory and cpu time consumption in the Ganglia Monitor of the cluster).

I still have the object ar in the Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 2):

You can get partial results for individual msg_ids. With map, each message corresponds to a chunk of the map (a list):

```
import ipyparallel as ipp

results = []
for msg_id in ar.msg_ids:
    chunk_ar = rc.get_result(msg_id)
    try:
        chunk = chunk_ar.get()
    except ipp.RemoteError as e:
        print('ignoring error: %s' % e)
    results.extend(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer given by minrk didn't work, because it failed already on `get_result`.

I modified it a bit and this worked for me:

```
results = []
for msg_id in ar.msg_ids:
    try:
        chunk_ar = rc.get_result(msg_id)
        chunk = chunk_ar.get()
    except:
        chunk = None
    results.append(chunk)
```

Note that I add `None`, such that I get an equal length list as the inputs.